# All the partitions of a natural number without restricting commutativity

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-combinatorics

Let us consider an infinit-degree polynomial, $p\left( \mathbf{x} \right)$:

$$p\left( \mathbf{x} \right)=\sum\limits_{\begin{smallmatrix} 
 \mathbf{v}\in {{\mathbb{N}}^{n}} \\ 
 {{v}_{1}}+{{v}_{2}}+...+{{v}_{n}}=m 
 \\ 
 m\in \mathbb{N} 
\end{smallmatrix}}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}{x_{i}^{{{v}_{i}}}}},$$

where $\mathbb{N}=[0,1,2,...]$ is the set of natural numbers. How to generate all the vectors $\mathbf{v}$ belonging to the integer $m\ge 0$ ?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I didn't formulate exactly. I have corrected the expression of $p\left( \mathbf{x} \right)$: I need all the vector $\mathbf{v}$ with fixed length $n$ such that the sum of their components equal to $m$ where $m$ is a fixed natural number.

Comment: [My answer to this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/868790) may be what you're looking for.