# How many ways can a natural number n be expressed as a sum of one or more positive integers, taking order into account?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Q: The number 4 can be expressed as a sum of one or more positive integers, taking order into account, in 8 ways: 
\begin{array}{l} 4&=1+3&=3+1&=2+2&=1+1+2\\
&=1+2+1&=2+1+1&=1+1+1+1. \end{array}
In general, given $\mathbb n$ $\in$ $\mathbb N$, how many ways can $\mathbf n$ be so expressed?

Query: I managed to solve it via a combinatoric proof, but the solution provided is as such:
\begin{align} &~~Idea: n= x_1 + x_2 +...+x_k, k \in \mathbb N, x_k \gt 0.\\
 &\implies x_1 - 1 + x_2 - 1 +...+ x_k -1 = n - k\\ 
 &\implies x_1* + x_2* + ... + x_k* = n-k \qquad-(*) \end{align}
Since $H^n_r$ = \begin{pmatrix} r+n-1 \\ r \end{pmatrix}, we have $H^k_{n-k}$ = 
\begin{pmatrix} n-k+k-1 \\ n-k \end{pmatrix}
And the answer is as such: $$\sum_{k=1}^n H^k_{n-k} =$$ $$\sum_{k=1}^n \begin{pmatrix} n-1 \\ n-k \end{pmatrix} = 2^{n-1}$$.
I have no idea why $H^n_r$ is applied and also why $$\sum_{k=1}^n H^k_{n-k}$$ is used to derive the desired result $$2^{n-1}$$. Some explanation on this will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Read about [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)).

Comment: This can be done using the standard "stars and bars" technique. Write $n$ 1s and in the $n-1$ gaps  between them we can choose either $0, 1, 2, \ldots, n-1$ gaps to put $+$ signs. Each such choice gives an ordered sum of integers with total $n$. Thus the number of ways is $\binom{n-1}{0}+\binom{n-1}{1}+\cdots + \binom{n-1}{n-1} = 2^{n-1}$.

Comment: Alright thanks all for helping out! :)

Comment: The expression $2^{n-1}$ is not right for $n=0$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen It is stated in the question that $\mathbf n$ ∈ $\mathbb N$ where $\mathbb N$ is a natural number so n $\ge$ 1.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

One way to see why the answer is $2^{n-1}$ directly is to write $n$ as a sum of $1$s:

$$ n = \underbrace{1 + 1 + 1 + ... + 1}_{n \textrm{ times}}. $$

Of course, this expresses $n$ as a sum of $1$s, but we want all expressions of $n$ as a sum of (ordered) positive numbers.  To do so, for each '$+$' in the expression above, we can choose whether or not to split the sum there to form a new summand.  For example, suppose $n = 8$.  Then we start with

$$ 8 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1. $$

Now suppose we choose to split the sum at the 2nd, 3rd and 5th plus signs, highlighted below.

$$ 8 = 1 + 1 \color{red}{+} 1 \color{red}{+} 1 + 1 \color{red}{+} 1 + 1 + 1. $$

We now add up the $1$'s between the chosen plusses to form the summands,

$$ 8 = (1+1) \color{red}{+} 1 \color{red}{+} (1+1) \color{red}{+} (1+1+1) = 2 \color{red}{+} 1 \color{red}{+} 2 \color{red}{+} 3,$$

giving an expression of $8$ as a sum of positive integers.

In general, this clearly bijects to all expressions of $n$ as an ordered sum of positive integers.  Since there are $n-1$ plus signs between the $n$ $1$s, there are $2^{n-1}$ ways of choosing where to split the sum, and hence $2^{n-1}$ possible sums.

Comment: This is a very good answer

Comment: Thanks!  I should credit Crostul, whose answer here (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868785#868790) was the first time I saw this representation of the stars and bars argument.

Answer (score 13):

What you are looking for is [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of $n$

Take a string of $1's,\;$ e.g.$\;   \large 1{\boxed.} 1\boxed. 1\boxed. 1$

In the $\;(n-1)\;$ boxes, either put a $+\;$ or a comma.

$1,\;\;1+1+1$ e.g. would represent $1+3$

Since you have $2$ choices for each box, # of compositions = $2^{n-1}$

Comment: This is equivalent to [Shagnik's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1907144/121411), above.

Comment: @Scott: Shakespeare: "Since brevity is the soul of wit / And tediousness the limbs and outward flourishes, I will be brief…"

Answer (score 4):

Since your title carefully distinguishes between natural numbers (which include $0$) and positive integers (which do not, at least not for the English sense of "positive"), I think a formula should be given that gives the proper value (namely $0$, since at least one summand was required)  for $n=0$, and $2^{n-1}$ does not do that. A correct formula would be $\lfloor2^{n-1}\rfloor$, or you could just give the value as
$$
  \begin{cases}0&\text{if $n=0$,}\\2^{n-1}&\text{if $n>0$.}\end{cases}
$$
The proof can be simply by induction, where we need $n=0$ *and* $n=1$ as starting cases to capture the exceptional behaviour at $n=0$ (both starting cases are obvious). If we assume for $n>0$ proved that there $2^{n-1}$ compositions of $n$, then from each of them we can get two different compositions of $n+1$: one by increasing the final term by one, and another by adding a new term $1$ and the end. It is clear that the first method, applied to all compositions of $n$ gives all compositions of $n+1$ that do not have $1$ as final term, and the other method gives all compositions of $n+1$ that do have $1$ as final term. Together that gives all compositions of $n+1$, and each of them in just one manner; their number is then $2^{n-1}\times2=2^n$, as was to be proved.

Note that the inductive step cannot be applied to the case $n=0$, as there is no final term to modify there; this explains the exception at the start of the sequence.

Comment: Is there unanimity that a natural number includes $0$ ? Wiki and Wolfram suggest otherwise.

Comment: @trueblueanil Of course there is no uniformity; there will always be heretics (regardless on which side you believe orthodoxy is). But somebody who in a single phrase utters both "natural number" and "positive integer" probably is trying to make a distinction. Besides, it never does harm to include consideration $n=0$ for a statement where it makes perfect sense.

Comment: You have a point !